# Google+'s Signin APis [AngularJS]: Refused to display 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

I've had a look to several similar problems on SO on this problems but I didn't find one which solves mine.

I'm following this tutorial to implement Google+'s Sign-in in my web application: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/06/angularjs-google-sign-integration/

**gapi** is loaded correctly.

In my controller I have the following code:

```
        gapi.signin.render('signInButton',
            {
                'callback': $scope.signInCallback, // Function handling the callback.
                'clientid': '[MY_CLIENT_ID].apps.googleusercontent.com', 
                'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity', 
                'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
            }
        );
```

where

MY_CLIENT_ID is of course replaced by my actual client ID got from Google Dashboard.

I'm working on localhost:85 and "Javascript origin" is set exactly to http://localhost:85/

The error I'm getting is:

> Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

**NOTE**: this error appears only sometimes. I don't understand why (the user interaction doesn't change, though).